# KMM Kotlin not configured

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to organize the project with kotlin multi-platform mobile, but there's a problem.

However, the shared module displays a warning message "Kotlin not configured" in the commonMain's kotlin file.

Where did it go wrong?

**Build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
//trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods).apply(false)
}
```

**Shared build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
iosX64()
iosArm64()
iosSimulatorArm64()

cocoapods {
    summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
    homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
    version = "1.0"
    ios.deploymentTarget = "16.0"
    podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
    framework {
        baseName = "shared"
        isStatic = true
    }
}

sourceSets {
    commonMain.dependencies {
    }
    commonTest.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
    }
  }
}
android {
namespace = "com.devjeong.watermelon_player"
compileSdk = 34
defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 24
  }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:+")
}
```

**libs.version.toml**
[image]

**shared.src.commonMain.Platform.kt**
[image]

---

1. Android Studio Version = Giraffe 2022.3.1 patch 4
2. gradle version = 8.1.3
3. Kotlin version = 1.9.20